# Finding Theta in Trigonometry

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have a quiz and on it is a trigonometry question. I am give a right triangle with all sides labeled. The only problem is they do not give me theta, and because of that I find myself choosing between the existing two angles. Sometimes I get it wrong because I cannot figure out how to find theta with all sides given. Here is the quiz so you can see for yourself. [*](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/basic-trigonometry/basic_trig_ratios/e/trigonometry_1)

[image]

Comment: I just figured it out. But I thank you for taking time out to help me..!!!! Yall are awsome!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need theta to know the tangent if you are given all of the side lengths.  The definition of tangent of the given angle is the opposite side length divided by the adjacent side length "y/x".

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!! Also how do you know the opposite, adjacent...etc then?

Comment: I have figured it out!!!!!!!! Thank you sooo muchhh!!!!! I wanna kiss you lool.

Answer (score 0):

tan is opposite side divided by adjacent side. So the answer is $5/10 = 1/2$

cosine is adjacent side/hypotenuse = $10/(5\sqrt 5) = 10 \sqrt 5/25$

sine is opposite/hypotenuse = $5/5\sqrt{5} = 5 \sqrt 5/25$

Note that the problem changes with each visit so do the math!

Comment: I understand but I dont.. I thank you for your time, but can you look at the quiz to know what im talking about @ https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/basic-trigonometry/basic_trig_ratios/e/trigonometry_1

Comment: I did, take a look at my answer. Mark the angle $BAC$ the angle at the top. 5 is opposite, 10 is adjacent and $5\sqrt5$ is the hypotenuse